# How to get child views of recyclerview for printing?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, pdf-generation

full view of all the items of recyclerview should be added to a single view.Is it possible in recyclerview. Right now I've done something like this,

```
for(int i=0; i<=adapter.getItemCount(); i++){
    View view = layoutManager.findViewByPosition(i);
}
```

But it is returning null for every iteration of "i".please suggest answer for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
YourViewHolder holder =  recyclerview.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position);
View view = holder.itemView;
//now you have the rootView for each row
```

Comment: yes,it is inside adapter class rite?.... is it not possible to get the view from outside adapter class?

Comment: it is outside the adapter class where you define your recyclerview..can be fragment or activity